# How to read/write from/to external drive in R

Tags: r, file

I have an external drive that I want to read and write `.txt` files to and from. Is there any way I can do this without having to change `setwd()` to the desired location? For example my external drive's location is: `/Volumes/ExtDrive/Folder1`

Can I specify desired output location in `write.table()`?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just specify full path.

Comment: With ./../file.txt etc. You can back one or more directory, useful for Linux environment.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik for example I have tried writing to my desktop with:  `write.csv(AAPL, "/Desktop/AAPL.csv")` but returns an error message

Comment: write.table(AAPL,"C:/Users/(your user name)/Desktop/AAPL.csv").  What error?  (assuming windows box)

Comment: If you're on Linux, this should be expanded by `~/Desktop/...`. For windows approach, see @mgriebe's comment.

Comment: thanks @RomanLuštrik I was leaving out the tilda I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by simply specifying the full file path (by creating an object or pasting the full path) in each of your read write calls. e.g.,

```
#set the data file
data <- read.table(file = "/Volumes/ExtDrive/Folder1/data.txt", ...)
#specify the file path for the output file
fpout <- "/Volumes/ExtDrive/Folder1/"
#output the datafile
write.table(x = "data.txt", file = fpout , ...)
```